# Varnish 6 No Config Files

Tags: varnish, amazon-linux

I've installed Varnish 6.06 on Amazon Linux 2, but there is no config file. I've generated the .vcl files, but from my past experience with varnish, there should be a configuration file in one of the following directories:

```
/etc/sysconfig/varnish
/etc/varnish/varnish.params
/etc/default/varnish
```

But I have nothing. Varnish starts as a service with no issues. I can also use varnishlog and varnishadm.
I installed it following the directions [here](https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish60lts/install#manual-rpm)
I need to change the VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT and a few DAEMON_OPTS. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Modern Linux systems use `systemd` for service management.

Please run the following command to edit the runtime parameters for Varnish:

```
sudo systemctl edit --full varnish
```

After editing you can run the following command to activate your changes:

```
sudo systemctl reload varnish
```